# Derivatives of determinants and trace with respect a scalar parameter

Tags: derivatives, determinant, trace

Consider the following two matrices, $A$ and $B.$ The dimension of both $A$
and $B$ are $n\times n,$ and all element of $A$ and $B$ depends on a scalar
parameter $\theta .$ Then what is derivatives of $\ln \left\vert
A\right\vert $ and $tr\left( AB\right) $ wrt to $\theta ?$ $\frac{\partial \ln \left\vert A\right\vert }{\partial \theta }$ and
$\frac{\partial tr\left( AB\right) }{\partial \theta }$? Any reference? Thanks

Comment: The trace is simple (it is a linear operation). For the determinant check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Derivative).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can you provide some extra link for my reference? I am not a math major, and I am trying to catch up the matrix algebra.

Answer (score 4):

For the first function, we have $$\eqalign{
\lambda &= \log(\det(A)) \cr\cr
d\lambda &= d\log(\det(A)) \cr
  &= d\operatorname{tr}(\log(A)) \cr
  &= A^{-T}:dA \cr
  &= A^{-T}:\frac{dA}{d\theta}d\theta \cr\cr
\frac{d\lambda}{d\theta} &= A^{-T}:\frac{dA}{d\theta} \cr
  &= \operatorname{tr}\Big(A^{-1}\frac{dA}{d\theta}\Big) \cr\cr
}$$ where colons denote the Frobenius inner product, and the differential of the trace-log is known as [Jacobi's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula#Corollary).

For the second function, $$\eqalign{
\tau &= \operatorname{tr}(AB) \cr
  &= A^T:B \cr\cr
d\tau &= dA^T:B + A^T:dB \cr
  &= B^T:dA + A^T:dB \cr
  &= \Big(B^T:\frac{dA}{d\theta} + A^T:\frac{dB}{d\theta}\Big)\,d\theta \cr\cr
\frac{d\tau}{d\theta} &= B^T:\frac{dA}{d\theta} + A^T:\frac{dB}{d\theta} \cr
 &= \operatorname{tr}\Big(B\frac{dA}{d\theta} + A\frac{dB}{d\theta}\Big) \cr\cr
}$$