# Derivative (w.r.t scalar) log of determinant of a Matrix.

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, logarithms, determinant

I need derivative of log determinant of $p\times p$ matrix $V^{-1}$ whose element is a function of $\phi$.
I used chain rule to derive the derivative. My calculation as follows.
$$\frac{\partial\log |V^{-1}|}{\partial \phi} = \frac{\partial\log |V^{-1}|}{\partial V^{-1}_{ij}}\frac{d V^{-1}_{ij}}{d\phi} = -(V^{-1})_{ji}\frac{d V^{-1}_{ij}}{d\phi}$$

where $V^{-1}_{ij}$ is element of $i$th row and $j$th column of $V^{-1}$.

Am I right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of the log determinant of a matrix $V$ with respect to a particular element $V_{ij}$ is the following:

$$
\frac{d}{V_{ij}} \log ( \det ( V ) ) = \frac{1}{\det(V)} C_{ij} = (V)^{-1}_{ji}
$$
where $C_{ij}$ are the elements of the cofactors matrix of $V$.

This is similar to your answer; however, I assume you are considering a matrix with elements that are functions of $\phi$, so $V$ has the following form:

$$
V = \begin{bmatrix} f_{11}(\phi) & \cdots & f_{1n}(\phi) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ f_{n1} (\phi) & \cdots & f_{nn}(\phi) \end{bmatrix}
$$

The derivative of $V$ with respect to $\phi$ is worked out in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2031818), which is the problem I believe you are asking about.

Comment: Thank you for your help~!! I believe your explanation will be helpful~!!